# HTML - Display specific image by clicking button

Tags: html, image

I've tried a couple hours to fix my issue, but I'm confused about the *Keyword* to find it

I've see a link that can show specific images like this :

[image: this one]

[image: another one]

what's the keyword of this method?

Comment: You're going to need to ask your question more thoroughly.

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: you can't do this with pure html, you will need to use some Javascript

Comment: @Jaberwocky i want to ask more detail about this, but i've laerned about __*What's have you tried*__ that's makes me cant ask a question more throughly, i just need to know the keyword, then research some tutorial, then when I stuck i'll ask again with specific question

Comment: @Just_Do_It how can i write a code when i dunno what's method of it?

Comment: @Maxiquester actually i don't know what's its should called, so i just need some keyword then searching some tutorial so i can go to the next step

Comment: about the link i've saw [this link](http://yudi.ga/) on portfolio menus, and i want to try it, but i dunno the right keyword to search

Comment: are you seeking something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16624525/how-to-display-an-image-when-pressing-a-button-in-html

Comment: @Just_Do_It i think it's what i needed, but i need some tutorial like w3school that given some code how-its-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems pretty vague, but you could use Isotope for the functionality you are looking for. It might be overkill, but it will allow you to build out what you have in your screenshot.

https://isotope.metafizzy.co/filtering.html

There is a getting started area to jumpstart you into building it out too:
https://isotope.metafizzy.co/#getting-started

Comment: that's what i really want, thanks in advance, but it's like 3rd party lib right?

Comment: Yes, but you could link directly to a CDN so you don't have to host the file. https://isotope.metafizzy.co/#cdn